# String can't be split by Tab or Space. Which character is this?

Tags: vb.net, intersystems-cache

I have this string which looks like this:

```
613 3503||0 82 1 49 1 1950 63543 11301 3 CORP-A1 1656.06 150 0 N 82.8 198.72 12.42 N 0 0 0 N Y 1
```

However, when I string split it by either TAB or SPACE, it does not split via Tab or space. It still outputs as the whole thing.

I tried the following:

```
= fromVisMtext.Text.Split(vbTab)
= fromVisMtext.Text.Split(" ")
```

Also, here at stack overflow when I pasted said string, it isn't delimited and is connected with each other.

```
6133503||0821491195063543113013CORP-A11656.061500N82.8198.7212.42N000NY1
```

The string I've pasted above was mine that I added white spaces manually, since here StackOverflow removes said delimiters.

Also, said string is from the VisM control of Intersystems Cache.

How can split this string by either Tab or Space? It doesn't seem to be either, but the data is definitely delimited by a white space or tab something.
[image: the string]

**EDIT** here is the result of `Dim theGlobals = String.Join(" ", fromVisMtext.Text.Select(Function(ch) Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(ch).ToString("x4")))`

[image]

Comment: Write the string to a file then examine the file with a hex editor to see the character value of the white space.

Comment: Or simply use the ToCharArray on your string and then build a loop that prints the integer conversion of each char. In this way you could find the real code of that 'white space' and choose the correct value to split

Comment: Based on your code, I deleted `c#` tag.

Comment: Your delimiter not a Space or a Tab, it is a Chr(1), look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243775/output-a-list-of-globals-or-a-single-global-value-with-vism/36259872#36259872) in your previous question, because your [original data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145577/intersystems-cachesql-database-globals-to-odbc-or-cachesql-client) in Cache contains $c(1)

Comment: The simplest thing should work without any kind of additional effort: 1. Generate the "original" output that shows that string, manually copy the unicode whitespace with **CTRL+C** (or null char, or whatever that could be), paste the character using **CTRL+V** in the VS code editor window, inside your double quotes ( `String.Split("here"c)` ). did you try it?.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I tried pasting it on Visual studio, but it did the same thing with Stackoveflow.. White space delimiters were removed.

Answer (score 1):

In general case (*space*, *tab*, *non breaking space* etc. separators) you can try split by *any white space*, e.g.:

```
  String source = @"613 3503||0 82 1 49 1 1950 63543 11301 3 CORP-A1 1656.06 150 0 N 82.8 198.72 12.42 N 0 0 0 N Y 1";

  var result = Regex
    .Split(source, @"\s")
    .Where(item => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item));
    //.ToArray(); // <- if you want to materialize

  // 613
  // 3503||0
  // 82
  // 1
  // ... 
  // N
  // Y
  // 1
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

If you´re *sure* that separators can be space (`' '`) or tab (`'\t'`) only you can just split:

```
  var result = source.Split(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: He's not sure, he doesn't know what character it is. Though if it's some kind of whitespace character, `Regex` should do it.

Comment: I tried the second one where I split by either ' ' or '\t'. the output ignored it. How can I split via regex?

Comment: @Malky.Kid: `Regex.Split(source, @"\s")` splits on every white space; `Regex.Split(source, @"[ \t]")` split on space and tabulation only.

Comment: @Malky.Kid: could you, please, provide the string you have problems with?

Comment: Here: 6133503||0821491195063543113013CORP-A11656.061500N82.8198.7212.42N000NY1 I swear that is the string... Stack overflow does remove the delimitation in it. I will post an image of its original appearance.

Comment: @Malky.Kid: Could you, please, *encode* your string: `String result = String.Join(" ", source.Select(ch => ((int) ch).ToString("x4")));` and provide the `result`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I apologize.. but may I ask for the VB.net counterpart of the said code?

Comment: Not sure, but in *VB.Net* it should be `String result = [String].Join(" ", from c in source select Int(c).ToString("x4"))`

Comment: Actually it should be:  `Dim result = String.Join(" ", source.Select(Function(ch) Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(ch).ToString("x4")))`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway it says `Overload resoution failed because no accessible 'Select' accepts this number of arguments.`

Comment: @Malky.Kid - I tested that code before I posted and it worked.  Make sure that your parentheses are correct or check for any extra commas.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Added an image of the results of the string